# How to transform text to input?

Tags: javascript, text, transform, helper, textinput

How can I create something such as:
- there is some text
- I click on it
- It transforms into an input that contains the text I clicked on.

Comment: Your english is not that bad.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this

HTML

```
<div onclick="transform(this)">Some text here</div>
```

Javascript

```
function transform(obj)
{
    obj.innerHTML = "<input type='text' value='" + obj.innerHTML + "' />";
}
```

Hope I've understood your question correctly.

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried it :/

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#" onclick="var input = document.createElement('input'); input.setAttribute('value', this.firstChild.nodeValue); this.parentNode.replaceChild(input, this);">here is some text</a>. Click it.
```

Instead of `<a>` you could also use `<span>` or `<div>` whatever you feel like.

Comment: Please explain what you mean. I tested the code before submitting it here and it worked for me...

Comment: When I click on the text, in the text input appears the text "null"

Comment: strange?! I tested with Opera and Firefox. what did you try? Did you embed the code somewhere?

Comment: Now it works :)!
Another request: can i set to the input an attribute such as "name"?

Comment: Now it works? What was wrong then? Yes of course you can set further attributes. Just like I set the value-attribute you can additionally write input.setAttribute('name', 'whateveryouwant');

Comment: Mh, my friend gave me his account to watch this.
http://pastebin.com/teCkMD9E --> This is what i want, but i don't know how to edit it; there appears a form not only the text input :/

Comment: So you want `<form>` tags and a submit button as well?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming HTML:

```
<p id='changeMe'>This is some text</p>
```

You can use jQuery:

```
$('#changeMe').click(function(){
    $this = $(this)
    $this.replaceWith( $('<input />').val( $this.text() ) )
})
```

See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/aXZ8e/

Comment: Can I give to the input also the attributes "text" and "name"?

Comment: yeah - like this `$('<input />').attr({type:'text',name:'whatever'}).val( $this.text() )`, or like this: `$('<input type="text" name="whatever" />').val( $this.text()`

Comment: This requres jQuery javascript library, which I would recommend for almost all websites as it simplifies code, and solves many cross platform issues. Also has some speed gain on various routines.

Comment: to set the name as well, just extend the corresponding line: `$this.replaceWith( $('<input />').val($this.text()).attr('name', 'yourDesiredName') )`

Answer (score 1):

```
<span id="target" onclick="javascript:run();" >This is dummy text</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
function run() {
  var span = document.getElementById( "target" );
  var text = span.innerHTML;
  var input = document.createElement("input");

  input.type = "text";
  input.value = text;

  span.innerHTML = "";
  span.appendChild( input );

  span.onclick = null;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I don't know why, but in the input there does not appear "This is dummy text" but appears "<input type="text">" :O

Comment: The problem is that the span still exists and it is therefore running the onclick function again. if you set onclick to null, this won't happen.